# Como buscar recursivamente usando o grep

Tags: linux, string, concatenação-de-string

Como buscar uma determinada palavra recursivamente em todos os arquivos do diretório atual e seus subdiretórios?

Tentei percorrer com:

```
find . | grep "palavra"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use o parâmetro `-r` do [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/).

```
grep -r "foo" .
```

Onde o `.` indica o diretório atual para iniciar a busca.

Se preferir procurar por uma palavra em arquivos com uma extensão especifica, você pode fazer:

```
grep -r "foo" ~/*.txt
```

Para ignorar as mensagens de aviso use parâmetro `-s` ou `--no-messages`:

```
grep -r -s "foo" ~/*.txt
```

A saída será semelhante há isto:

```
 ~$ grep -r -s "foo" ~/*.txt

 /home/user/file1.txt:foo
 /home/user/file2.txt:foo
 /home/user/file3.txt:foo
 ~$
```

Comment: Eu usei assim ---------- grep  -nRHI "palavra" *

Comment: Obrigado, entendir @thiago

Answer (score 4):

Também é possível utilizar a opção `-exec` do `find` juntamente com o `grep`. Se houver necessidade de filtrar os arquivo com o `find` a opção abaixo vai ser mais rápida do que `grep -r`, pois não vai tentar fazer a busca da "palavra" em todos os arquivos:

```
find . -exec grep 'palavra' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

ainda acho que o melhor poderia ser o

grep -ir "palavra" .

para pesquisar qualquer ocorrência case sensitive

Comment: você quis dizer case-insensitive, certo?

Comment: provavelmente heheheh

Answer (score 1):

Espero que este ajude:
grep -R "Palavra" ./

Comment: Seria interessante explicar sua resposta, para facilitar a compreensão de como isso ajuda a resolver o problema

Answer (score 0):

Apenas complementando as outras respostas, acho que vale explicar porque o seu comando não funcionou (além de dar uma outra alternativa que não foi citada).

Primeiro, sobre o comando:

```
find . | grep "palavra"
```

O que o *pipe* (o `|`) faz é pegar a saída do primeiro comando e passar como entrada para o segundo. Como `find .` traz a listagem de todos os arquivos e diretórios (partindo do diretório atual), então na verdade o `grep` está fazendo a busca por "palavra" nos **nomes** desses arquivos e diretórios. Ou seja, se tiver algum arquivo ou diretório cujo **nome** contenha "palavra", ele será retornado.

Para que a saída do comando `find .` seja passada como argumentos para o `grep` (e este faça a busca no conteúdo do arquivo), você pode usar a opção `-exec`, como já sugerido em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10680/112052), ou então usar [`xargs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "palavra"
```

`xargs` pega a saída do `find` (ou seja, os nomes do arquivos) e os passa como parâmetros para `grep`, assim a busca por "palavra" será feita no conteúdo desses arquivos (e não mais no nome).

A opção `-type f` busca apenas pelos arquivos, ignorando os diretórios (pois `grep` dá erro se você passar um diretório como parâmetro).

A opção `-print0` imprime os nomes dos arquivos com o [*NULL CHARACTER*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0/index.htm) entre eles (em vez de imprimir um por linha, como é o *default* do [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)). E a opção `-0` faz com que `xargs` use o *NULL CHARACTER* como separador. Assim, casos os nomes dos arquivos tenham espaços, *new lines*, aspas, etc, estes serão interpretados e passados corretamente para `grep` (sem esta opção, muitos nomes de arquivos com os caracteres já citados podem ser passados incorretamente e `grep` dará erro).

Uma diferença para a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10680/112052) é que `-exec` executa o comando várias vezes (uma vez para cada arquivo encontrado), enquanto o `xargs` agrupa vários arquivos de uma vez, resultando em menos execuções do `grep` (inclusive, você pode controlar quantos arquivos são passados por vez, com `--max-args`, ou então quantos caracteres podem ser passados a cada execução, com `--max-chars` - consulte a [documentação](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) para mais opções).